# Trouble finding a fuse

Tags: honda, fuse, vents

I have a 2011 Honda Civic, and I'm having trouble with the ventilation system.

When I turn on the blower I can hear (and even see when I remove the cabin air filter) that the fan is working.  However no air is coming out of the vents.  I read that this can be caused by a blown fuse, but I can't see any that are burnt.  What are the fuses I should check?

[Here](https://www.autogenius.info/honda-civic-2010-2011-fuse-box-diagram/) are the diagrams.

Comment: Where is the air coming out now?  There are three choices here 1) The defrost grill on top of the instrument panel 2) the panel registers or 3) floor nozzles that aim air at your feet.  If the fan is spinning I doubt you have a fuse issue. More likely a mode door controller problem.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair!

Comment: @zipzit It's the third choice.  I didn't notice this before, but the air is coming out at my feet, and it wont change back to the normal vents (or any of the other ones for that matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fan is working, I'm guessing you have a mode door or actuator problem within the Heating, Ventilation and Air Conditioning (HVAC) air handling system. The HVAC system is uses small electric motor actuators to control plastic doors.

- There is a blend door for temperature (full cool, full heat or somewhere in between)
- There is a recirculation door for outside air (useful in the summer to improve air conditioning performance)
- There is one (or more) mode doors that determine where the air exits the system (defroster, panel-vents, or floor)

[image: Honda HVAC system]

I'm pretty sure your mode door controller is having troubles.  Its possible the motor is burnt out.  It's also possible that the plastic door is broken or cracked inside the HVAC system.

Actually you can perform a test for this yourself. Sit in the car in the front passenger seat.  Turn on the ignition power (Do NOT start the car!) . Turn off the radio.  Place blower controller on its lowest setting.  Now place the system in different modes (Floor/Heating, Panel/Ventilation, Defrost).  It may help to open the glove box.  You are going to want to listen carefully to what the system is doing.   If you can hear absolutely nothing, that's probably a dead actuator motor.  Pretty easy fix. Parts are $40 or so.  If however you hear the electric motor turning, accompanied with a bunch of clicks, that indicates you may stripped plastic gears inside the motor actuator, or even that you have a broken plastic door.  The motor actuator has a keyed shaft and that key is slipping.  Do note, if that door is broken, this is a big repair job, involving removing the instrument panel, replacing the HVAC system, etc.

Do note.. If you are stuck in floor mode, this has to be fixed.  ITS DANGEROUS to be driving this car in the winter, particularly if it is raining or snowing. Your windshield can fog up and you won't be able to see the road to drive safely. No amount of driving will help, in fact continued driving will continue to fog the windshield in certain weather conditions.

https://youtu.be/1aVzyMOsArw

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to check... the air intake for recirculated air is probably in the glove compartment. If you had plastic bags in there they could have been sucked in and be blocking the system. Happened to me last month with a Honda Jazz. Symptoms were very similar and switching to fresh intake didn’t alleviate the problem as you might expect.